# Create index on big table increase IO:XactSync wait event for other sessions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, aws-aurora

AWS Aurora (postgres 11.9) after downgrading instance from db.r6g.8xlarge to db.r6g.4xlarge instance and enabling logical_replication

I'm trying to rebuild indexes (cause of bloat) for table size 30GB (actualy first time I tried to make this excercise for table 400+GB, but the same result)

SQL: create index concurrenrtly ...

after 5 minutes of execution
write throughput parameter increases to ~ 150 mb/sec and other dml sessions  caught dramaticaly increasing IO:XactSync waits
We did not have such issues before downgrading....
Please help to find, What's may be a reason of such behavior.
P.S We have about 300 transactions/per second for this DB

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sounds like you reindex is consuming so much IO it is depriving other sessions.  Maybe scale back up until after the reindex has finished.

Comment: Thanks jjanes. Yes sounds like you wrote,  When we used r6g.8xlarge machine - we could create indexes on tables about 400GB size without any spikes and impacts on our applications
After downgrading to r6g.4xlarge  - we could NOT create indexes on tables about 30GB size... This was some kind of unpredictable behaviour for us. Is it such big difference between machines?